# Image texturing to mix materials is not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am modeling an LP and want to mix the photo of the cover with some worn edges, since it doesnt work I tried it with just 2 colors but it still doesnt work and I dont understand why. I UV unwrapped the cube with cube projection.

It is not visible in the screenshot but the image texture I paint on is the right one (LP_Texture_Paint)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify this for me: Are you trying to overlay an image texture or are you trying to texture paint? (Or are you trying to texture paint an image texture?)

Comment: I am not sure what the differences between those are but I am guessing I am trying to texture paint. I am trying to paint a texture black and white and use it as a factor to mix 2 shaders.

Comment: Can you try plugging an UV Map node to specifically call the UV mapping name into the texture node or use a Texture Coordinate node to generically assign the UV map to it? Also, can you double check normals are correct direction? Seems to me to be number one culprit when texpaint fails to show up.

Comment: For me, I use an *Attribute Node*'s "Color" output as the input for the *fac* on a *Mix Shader* node. Then, I select the mesh, go to Edit Mode, select all the vertices, and make a new vertex group in the *Object Data Properties* panel. Then, go to Texture Paint mode, and paint! (basically, one color is one texture inputted into the *Mix Shader* node, and another color is the other texture.)

Comment: @CraigDJones Thank you! That was the problem. Plugging in the Coordinate Node and Texture Mapping solved it. Weirdly I also have to leave rendered view and go back into it to view the result.

Comment: Comment from Craig D Jones is the answer that solved my problem.